# SniffStep not working on Carte server

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I am executing a transformation in a Carte server. And the transformation runs just fine, it ends up with a finished status, it shows the read and written rows per step, and the execution logs.

[image]

However, when I perform a sniff-step like this: http://localhost:9080/kettle/sniffStep/?trans=Add+a+sequence+-+Basic+example&step=Generate+Rows&xml=Y&lines=10 
It returns a empty xml: `<step-sniff></step-sniff>`

I don't understand what is happening, since I can see in the table that Generate Rows has written 10 rows. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This sniffing step works only for transformation that is currently running and the sniffing step is being executed, i.e. sniffing step is not finished. Most of the time you have to be very fast for transformations which finish fast.

Build 'Delay Row' step after the sniffing step. This forces the sniffing step to be executed for a longer time. In this case, you may be able to see some rows while sniffing.